# Find all integral solutions of $x^2+xy+y^2=x^2y^2$.

Tags: number-theory

Find all integral solutions of $x^2+xy+y^2=x^2y^2$.

$Source:$ $Problem$ $Solving$ $Strategies$ $by$ $Arthur$ $Engel$

**My Approach:**

I was able to find the fact that $x,y$ must have the same parity i.e. either both must be odd or both even.
I proved this by contradiction:

Taking $x$ to be odd and $y$ to be even$\\$
$x^2y^2=$ $odd^2$$even^2$$\\$
$\Rightarrow$ $x^2y^2$ is even {R.H.S is even}$\\$
$x^2+xy+y^2$ = $odd^2+odd.even +even^2$$\\$
$\Rightarrow$ $x^2+xy+y^2$ is odd {L.H.S is odd}$\\$
However this contradicts that L.H.S = R.H.S$\\$
Hence either $x,y=0(mod2)$ or $x,y=1(mod2)$$\\$
However I am not able to move further than above, small hints as to how to  continue my way, would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** The solution mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644890/if-x-y-in-mathbb-z-solve-x2xyy2-x2y2) -  is based on factorization but I need a more number theoretic approach like by using Infinite Descent.

Comment: Usuallt, the right-hand side islarger than the left-hand side.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2171077/ (mainly for positive integers) and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169585/

Comment: If $p$ divides $x$ then it must divide $y$, and vice versa.

Comment: @player3236 i actually need a more number theoretic approach rather than the one mentioned in that post.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "more number theoretic approach", but if this translates to "no factorization" to you, then you could simply set $y$ as a variable and $x$ as a parameter, solve the quadratic equation for $y$ where you will find that for $x^2 \neq 1$, you would need $4x^2-3$ to be a square, which doesn't exist. In the end, you will be left with the exact same solutions as already provided in the multiple other answers.

Comment: "Engel - Problem Solving". I have got that book. What page is this problem from?

Comment: @Raffaele page - 132 question - 49